# Transport rule to remove recipient when shared mailbox is on recipients

Tags: exchange-2013

We have a shared mailbox say Accounts Payable, and Bill and John both have access.

Our users have a bad habit of sending e-mails to the Accounts Payable shared mailbox but also add Bill and John to their e-mail (either in To or CC).

Is it possible to create a rule to remove Bill and John from these e-mails, but still allow the e-mail to flow through to the Accounts Payable shared mailbox as desired?

Obviously Bill and John still need to be able to receive e-mail, just not when the user has also included Accounts Payable.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. You will have to add a transport rule that will check the email addresses to To and CC and if they contain the 2 users and the primary email address the email will be dropped from these two ones. If you are still having the case as the question is a little old let me know.

Comment: I have this exact issue with Office 365 and am unable to find a way to accomplish it with the Mail Flow Rules section.  Do you know if this functionality is available, and if so can you provide some more detail?